# How to fix a cell that is not automatically updating due to a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have cell that updates a balance with any expenses. Because there is no subtract function in excel, I wrote this simple macro:

```
Private Function SubtractChecking(cell As Range)
    Dim currentBalance As Single
    currentBalance = cell.Value

    SubtractChecking = currentBalance - WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B7:M23"))
End Function
```

The function works but the cell that holds this function does not update the calculations automatically; I checked that the Excel calculation options are set to automatic. I either have to double click on the cell to update it or use Ctrl-Shift-Alt-F9 to update. I figured it had to do with the macro but I have no clue.

Comment: *Because there is no subtract function in excel* ?? What about `-` operator ??

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a range reference into the function as a parameter for the currentBalance but not the range to modify the balance.

```
Private Function SubtractChecking(cell As Range, vals as range)
    Dim currentBalance As Single

    currentBalance = cell.Value2
    SubtractChecking = currentBalance - WorksheetFunction.Sum(vals)

End Function
```

Usage: `=SubtractChecking(A1, B7:M23)`

Using native worksheet function SUM: `=sum(a1, -sum(B7:M23))`

Comment: Yes, for this case, also a solution and might be the better one as you avoid `volatile`,  upvoted. But I think in general as stated in my answer you need to use `Application.volatile` .

Comment: I wouldn't want the function to recalculate on a volatile frequency; adding the range into the parameters ensures it will only recalculate when 'dirty'.

Comment: Totally agree. If you can avoid `volatile` then your suggestion is IMO the best way.

Answer (score 3):

The general answer to the question "update the calculations automatically" is that you have to use `Application.Volatile`
In this case

```
Private Function SubtractChecking(cell As Range)
    Dim currentBalance As Single
    Application.Volatile
    currentBalance = cell.Value

    SubtractChecking = currentBalance - WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B7:M23"))

End Function
```

But, of course, Michal's comment is also right: Why don't you use `-`?